# how many useState updates per second react supports?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on an application that receives streams of market data from a websocket, (socket.io) on a react APP. This streams refers to differents stocks and I can have up to 20 streams per second.

The component that receives this streams, neets to pass them each stream to child components that shows price variation and relevant analytics for each stock

The way I found to simple share this data streams from parent to childs is to create a variable stream:

```
const Portfolio = () => {
...
const [message, setMessage] = useState({ticker:undefined, last_price:undefined});
useEffect(() => {
    socket?.on('newstreamdata', async(data) => {
      try {
          setMessage(data)
      } catch (err) {
          console.log(err.message)
  }})
  }, [socket]);
 ...
 <Asset message={message}>
 <Asset message={message}>
 <Asset message={message}>
```

The asset on the other side checks if the streams is usefull and proceeds

```
 const Asset = (stream) => {
 ...
     useEffect(()=>{
         if (message.ticker == asset_ticker) {
             setPrice(message.last_price)
         }
     },[message])
 ...
 }
```

So far seems to work althought I am doing validations and testings. Regarding this approach my question us:

- Will I be missing streams? I am afraid that if setUpdates runs to quick the Asset component might loose the oportunity to use a relevant stream. May be I am hitting the limit of useState updates.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem could be you useEffect hook. You wrote that a new event handler is registered on each socket change. Ideally, you create the socket instance with the useEffect once (empty dependency array) as well the event handlers for on events.

Comment: yes, that dependendy is to let the socket recognize when there is a new stream of data on the websocket. I'll make it clear on the code. thanks